# open VPN issue on Mac connecting fileshare

Tags: macos, vpn, openvpn, nas, qnap

I have a qnap NAs where I use QVPN service with open VPN. Under windows the connection works fine and I can access all shares. If I do the same with a mac it also connects to the NAS without problems. But, it can not access the shares. Can't even ping the NAS.

Message on ping is: Request timeout for icmp_seq0 ping: sendto: Host is down

ping: sendto: no route to host

Someone has an idea for me what I can do?

Comment: OpenVPN server and Mac client config is required to troubleshoot - please post both in separate code boxes _(please anonymize info such as DDNS or WAN IP, port #, etc.)_. Please also change OpenVPN server log verbosity to `verb 4` and Mac client config to `verb 5`, then restart the OpenVPN server, reconnect with the Mac, and try to access a share and ping the NAS. Once both fails, please post the server and client logs in separate code boxes, also anonymizing info such as DDNS, WAN IP, server port #, etc.